# Is the word マガ a shortened form for マガジン ?

Tags: translation

Is the word マガ a shortened form for マガジン ?

Comment: I thought it was short for "Trump"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is.  However, it is not that we refer to any magazine as マガ.  Instead, we use it to shorten an existing magazine name or a compound katakana word if it contains マガジン in it.

ヤングマガジン (name of popular comic magazine) is shortened to ヤンマガ.

メールマガジン (= "e-newsletter" in English)  is shortened to メルマガ.

We never say something like 「[電車]{でんしゃ}に[乗]{の}る[前]{まえ}にマガを[買]{か}おう。」 = "Let's grab some magazines before hopping on the train!"  In this case, we will use the word [雑誌]{ざっし}, not マガジン or let alone マガ.